# ¿Cómo puedo crear un fichero txt solo de las palabras alfanuméricas que contiene otro fichero txt? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for

Tengo un fichero txt con varias palabras, numéricas, alfabéticas y alfanuméricas. Este fichero se llama passwords.txt

Quiero crear dos ficheros, uno con las palabras numéricas y otro con las palabras alfanuméricas.

He conseguido crear el fichero de las palabras numéricas y alfabéticas pero no consigo el de las alfanuméricas, porque al utilizar str.isalnum me aparece todo el contenido del fichero txt.

```
''' #22. Crear dos ficheros uno para las contraseñas alfanuméricas y otro para las que son numéricas.
b = open("/home/mariluz/jupyter/passwords.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
passw_alfan = b.read()
string_value = passw_alfan.split()
alfan = ' '.join(filter(str.isalnum, string_value))
print(alfan)

original_stdout = sys.stdout 

with open("/home/mariluz/jupyter/passwords_alfanum.txt", 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
    print(alfan)
    sys.stdout = original_stdout
'''
```

Por otra parte, he intentado crear dos listas, una que contenga las contraseñas numéricas y otra que contenga las alfanuméricas. Pero los ficheros txt me salen en blanco. ¿Sabéis por qué?

Pongo el código y un pantallazo por si lo veis mejor.

```
    #22. Crear dos ficheros uno para las contraseñas alfanuméricas y otro para las que son numéricas.
digitos=list()
alphanum=list()

file = open("/home/mariluz/jupyter/passwords.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
passwords = file.read()
palabras = passwords.split()
def digitos_contraseñas():
    digitos = 0
    alphanum = 0
    
    for c in cadena:
        if c.isdigit():
            digitos = digitos.append(c)
        elif c.isalnum():
            alphanum = alphanum.append(c)
        else:
            pass
    return digitos, alphanum

textfile = open("/home/mariluz/jupyter/alphanum_file.txt", "w")
for element in alphanum:
     textfile.write(element + "\n")
textfile.close()
 
textfile = open("/home/mariluz/jupyter/digitos_file.txt", "w")
for element in digitos:
     textfile.write(element + "\n")
textfile.close()
```

[image: Pantallazo crear listas y fichero txt]

Por favor, ¿me podéis ayudar a obtener un fichero con las palabras que son alfanuméricas?

Gracias,

Un saludo

Comment: ¿En qué momento estas llamando al método 'digitos_contraseñas'? Si no lo llamas no puedes obtener los valores que has separado. Los ficheros que estás escribiendo están vacíos porque no estás escribiendo ninguna información, no estás separando en ningún momento los valores.

Comment: Hola, a ver, mi razonamiento es el siguiente: lo primero digo que dígitos y alphanum son una lista vacía. 
Luego le digo que me abra el fichero, y lo convierto en split.
A continuación defino una variable, y le digo que dígitos contraseñas está compuesto por, lo que encuentre que sea solo números y para ello utilizo c.isdigit(), y por las palabras que sean alfanuméricas, y para ello utilizo c.isalnum(), del resto le digo que no haga nada. Solicito que me devuelva dígitos y alphanum y luego le digo que cree un fichero con alphanum y otro fichero con dígitos. ¿no? Es que no lo veo.

Comment: También me han dado como pista que pruebe con print([i for i in milita if not i.isalpha()]) pero tampoco me sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el código que me indicó Candid Moe, pude sacar los dos ficheros.

He encontrado otra forma de hacerlo, la pongo por si le sirve a alguien más.
Sería la siguiente:

```
    #22. Crear dos ficheros uno para las contraseñas alfanuméricas y otro para las que son numéricas.

nuevo_alfa= r"/home/mariluz/jupyter/alphanum_file.txt"
nuevo_num =r"/home/mariluz/jupyter/digitos_file.txt"

file = open("/home/mariluz/jupyter/passwords.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
passwords = file.read()
palabras = passwords.split()

contraseñas_alfanum = ([i for i in palabras if not i.isalpha() if not i.isdigit()])
contraseñas_num = ([i for i in palabras if i.isdigit()])
print(contraseñas_alfanum)
print(contraseñas_num)
with open(nuevo_alfa, 'w') as archivo_salida_alfa:
    archivo_salida_alfa.write(str(contraseñas_alfanum))
with open(nuevo_num, 'w') as archivo_salida_num:
    archivo_salida_num.write(str(contraseñas_num))
```

Gracias, por mi parte se podría cerrar esta duda.
Un saludo

Comment: Si quieres "cerrar" una duda, puedes marcar tu respuesta como aceptada (cuando el sistema te lo permita)

Answer (score 0):

Una solución:

```
with open("passwords.txt", "r") as passwords:
    with open("numericos.txt", "w") as numericas:
        with open("otros.txt", "w") as otros:
            for palabra in passwords:
                try:
                    valor = int(palabra)
                    numericas.write(palabra)
                except ValueError:
                    if any(x.isdigit() for x in palabra):
                        otros.write(palabra)
```

Este código procesa todo en una sola pasada, sin necesidad de listas intermedias.

El ciclo `for` recorre las palabras del archivo de passwords. Por cada una intenta convertirla a entero. Si resulta, es una password numérica. Si falla, es otra cosa.

#### Demo

**passwords.txt**

```
1232455
a15
romeo
alfa
67
0
100299-23
```

produce:

**numericos.txt**

```
1232455
67
0
```

**otros.txt**

```
a15
romeo
alfa
100299-23
```

Comment: Gracias Cándido Moe, se me han creado los dos ficheros perfectamente. Pero, por favor, para que yo lo entienda, ¿cómo sabe el programa que numéricas debe contener las contraseñas que son sólo números? ¿Esto viene predefinido en Python? Quiero decir, siempre que yo ponga "... as numericas" ¿me va a sacar la información numérica del documento que le indique?
¿Hay alguna forma de sacar sólo las alfanuméricas? Las alfabéticas no, solo las alfanuméricas.Quizás, mis preguntas son un poco de bombero, pero llevo solo dos semanas con esto y voy muy perdida,quiero entenderlo para interiorizarlo.Gracias

Comment: @MariLuz Los nombres de los ficheros son completamente arbitrarios. Los nombres no significan nada; eres tú quien decide en que fichero vas a grabar.

Comment: Vale, lo acabo de pillar. Salen solo números porque le estamos indicando int. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @MariLuz Usamos `int` pues si funciona, entonces la palabra es numérica. Si falla, se produce una excepción, atrapada por el `except`y ahi sabemos que no es número

Comment: Gracias Candid Moe. Ahora solo me falta quitar las que son alfabéticas y dejar solo las afanuméricas. He probado quitando int y poniendo isalnum, hexdigits, pero lógicamente no me sale. ¿Tú sabes cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: @MariLuz. Edite la respuesta para incluir la condición de que sólo grabe las palabras que contengan al menos un digito.